# Multiple Wars sharing common EJB JAR

Tags: jboss7.x, ejb-3.0, war, ear

I have a jar that contains many EJBs and I need to access those from multiple WARs. I'm trying to figure out the best way to package and deploy these to a single app server.

Currently, I deploy each WAR individually with each having a dependency on the common EJB jar, but this seems to be incredibly inefficient (memory-wise et al) as there are separate JNDI bindings for each application.

I've also tried packaging these WARs in an EAR but this doesn't seem to change anything.

Does this make any sense? How can I make sure that the common EJB jar is not "deployed" multiple times (once for each WAR  that depends on it)?

Comment: You should have one ear with 3 modules - 2 wars and 1 ejb. Do not include EJB in the WARs as you will have duplicates. Dependency should result only in classpath setting, not including jar in wars.

Comment: if I set the scope to provided in each WARs pom.xml - will this accomplish this?

Comment: This should prevent jar being included, but I'm not sure whether it will be visible at runtime. If not you will have to add ejbmodule.jar to ClassPath in the MANIFEST.MF file.

Comment: Alright thanks! I'll give that a try soon!

Comment: Add sample pom.xml for one of your modules, if it won't work. As you might be need to change dependency to ejb or add a <manifestEntries><Class-Path>project-ejb-${project.version}.jar</Class-Path>

Comment: Finally got back around to this! Your suggestions worked! I added the shared lib as a module in the ear and ClassPath entries in each war. The only other thing was adding the <skinnyWars>true</skinnyWars> config to the configuration block of the ear plugin. If you post everything as an answer I'd be glad to accept!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your issue you need to have one ear with 3 modules - 2 wars and 1 ejb. Do not include EJB in the WARs as you will have duplicates. Dependency should result only in classpath setting, not including jar in war files.

Classpath entry might be created via war plugin configuration

```
 <manifestEntries><Class-Path>project-ejb-${project.version}.jar</Class-Path>
```

or ear plugin configuration:

```
<skinnyWars>true</skinnyWars>
```

See [skinnyWars](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/examples/skinny-wars.html) description for more details.